# How to destructure object containing functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have the following React component:

```
import { AppInterface } from 'pages/_app'

export default class SiteNavBtn extends React.Component {

    static contextType = AppInterface

    render() {

        const { actions } = this.context 
        const { toggleSiteNav } = actions || {}

        return(
            <button className="site-nav-btn" onClick={ () => toggleSiteNav() }>
                <i className="icon"><span>Open menu</span></i>
            </button>
        )

    }   

}
```

With the above code, if `this.context` is undefined and I click on the button, an error complains that `toggleSiteNav` is not a function (as expected), so I have set an empty function as a default value for it:

```
const { actions } = this.context 
const { toggleSiteNav = () => {} } = actions || {}
```

This works, meaning that if `this.context` is undefined, when I click on the button now nothing happens of course but I don't get an error, however I believe I am invoking an empty function. Is this correct or is there a better way to destructure an object that contains functions and that may be undefined?

Comment: I personally just wouldn't register the event if the callback does not exist. Otherwise, I would make a generic callback that process the click request and handles what to do if the desired callback does not exist.

Comment: It seems fine to me. You can just put `onClick={toggleSiteNav}` in this case.

Comment: Code seems fine to me and as mentioned this `onClick={ () => toggleSiteNav() }` can be writte as `onClick={toggleSiteNav}`

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, you could however write it like this:

```
const { actions: { toggleSiteNav = () => {} } = {} } = this.context;
...
<button onClick={toggleSiteNav} ...
```

Or simply not attach the handler if it is falsy:

```
const { actions: { toggleSiteNav } = {} } = this.context;
...
<button onClick={toggleSiteNav ? toggleSiteNav : null} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move some of your code to a separate function:

```
import { AppInterface } from 'pages/_app'

 export default class SiteNavBtn extends React.Component {

        static contextType = AppInterface

        toggleSiteNav(){
             const { actions } = this.context 
             const { toggleSiteNav } = actions || {};
             if(typeof toggleSiteNav === 'function'){
                   toggleSiteNav ();
             }

        }


        render() {

            return(
                <button className="site-nav-btn" onClick={ () => this.toggleSiteNav() }>
                    <i className="icon"><span>Open menu</span></i>
                </button>
            )

        }   

    }
```